# Why isn't this callback being executed during this unit test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have a simple db object with a addItem function:

```
exports.addItem = function(item, callback){

    var callbackFunc = callback || function(){};

    list.push(item);

    callbackFunc(item);
};
```

And a controller that calls it:

```
exports.addItem = function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    db.addItem(req.body,function(item){
        res.send(item);
    });
};
```

Finally a unit test:

```
var item =require('path/to/item/controller');
var mockReq = {
    body: itemObj
};

var mockRes = {
    setHeader : function(){},
    send : function(item){}
};

describe('list item', function(){

     it('should respond with item added', function(done){
            spyOn(mockRes, 'send');

            item.addItem(mockReq, mockRes);

            expect(mockRes.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(itemObj);
        });
});
```

Every time I run the test I get the following error:

```
 Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL
```

I've tried with both the real db object, and by injecting a mock db object that only calls the callback function with the item. Both get the same error.

Comment: You are not calling `done` anywhere. Jasmine doesn't know when your unit test was suppose to finish. The other issue is that at the moment you are calling `expect`, the `db` callback likely hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: How can I pass it the done function? The item controller doesn't expose the db object.

Comment: derp needed to remove the done. It was left after a refactor, and I didn't even see it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the structure doesn't make it very easy. Not sure what the best way is, but you could provide a mock implementation for `send` which would call `done`. That would then also include your `expect` call. *edit:* Well, if you are testing async code then you have to use `done` AFAIK. If you are mocking the DB anyway then maybe not.

Comment: The done argument isn't necessary in this instance. Removing it from the test fixed the issue.

Comment: This works as well `spyOn(mockRes, 'send').and.callFake(done());` I suppose this approach is more safe.

Comment: Should be `spyOn(mockRes, 'send').and.callFake(done);` though. Otherwise you call `done` immediately, not when `send` is called.

Comment: If you add your answer, I'll accept it.